# Language Translator Node in node red fail with "Model not found" if languages are set dinamically

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, node-red

The Node-RED Info tab for Watson IoT Language Translator states: Source and destination language parameters can be configured through the editor panel or set dynamically using the language codes in the following properties, msg.srclang and msg.destlang. Trying to set it to "en" and "it" in a function node before the call to the node, but the Watson IoT Language Translator node still fail with "Model not found" error.

[image: Flow example]

Are there some solution for it ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Node configuration has defaulted, the domain that is being picked up is that of the configuration, which happens to not be 'news', hence its trying to use 'conversation en-it' which isn't available.

setting

```
msg.domain = 'news'
```

should resolve the problem.